# Skipping arrays in a multi-dimensional array during loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Supposing I have agents stored in a multidimensional array with the following structure :

```
[Agent - 167] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-17 00:01:51.417080
                    [1] => Agent - 167
                    [2] => LOGIN
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-17 00:02:28.821206
                    [1] => Agent - 167
                    [2] => LOGOUT
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-17 00:02:37.257944
                    [1] => Agent - 167
                    [2] => LOGIN
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-21 07:16:51.457435
                    [1] => Agent - 167
                    [2] => LOGIN
                )
       [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-21 07:20:51.016638
                    [1] => Agent - 167
                    [2] => LOGOUT
                )
    )
```

I would like to calculate the time difference between each `Login` and `Logout` events for each agent and get the aggregate. This is straight forward enough as the time logs are in the first element of the inner array so `[0][0] = Time`. The event is on the third element. My calculation is only valid when the following event is a `LOGOUT` and the previous event is a `LOGIN`.

Sometimes however the Agent times out instead of logging out which logs two `LOGIN` events in succession, I would like to skip the array which has a `LOGIN` event **IF** the next array also has a `LOGIN` event and continue my calculation.

I am using the below code to perform my calculation:

```
  foreach ($pse_array as $value) {
        $total = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i+=2) {
            $srtTime = strtotime($value[$i][0]);
            $endTime = strtotime($value[$i + 1][0]);
            $interval = $endTime - $srtTime;
            $total += $interval;
        }
        echo gmdate("H:i:s", $total) . " Minutes <br>";
    }
```

I am also aware that I can make a comparison to check if the events meet my criteria with an `If statement` but i'm not sure how I would skip the array.

Comment: maybe it is better to add timeuot time?

Comment: @splash58 Probably is but I can't redesign the system.

Comment: $pse_array is array from var_dump? Or it is $value?

Comment: @splash58 Yes it is. It's the outermost array of the Multi-dimensional array.

Comment: filter the array first, then do the calculations on the filtered array. Code will look a lot cleaner that way. Also need to check that you don't overshoot the array length when you increment index. Can do this in filter also to remove last `LOGIN` that doesn't have a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a quick and easy solution after a few attempts

```
$pse_array = [ 'Agent - 167' => [
        [ 0 => '2015-07-17 00:01:51.417080',
            1 => 'Agent - 167',
            2 => 'LOGIN'
        ],
        [
            0 => '2015-07-17 00:02:28.821206',
            1 => 'Agent - 167',
            2 => 'LOGOUT'
        ],
        [
            0 => '2015-07-17 00:02:37.257944',
            1 => 'Agent - 167',
            2 => 'LOGIN'
        ],
        [
            0 => '2015-07-21 07:16:51.457435',
            1 => 'Agent - 167',
            2 => 'LOGIN'
        ],
        [
            0 => '2015-07-21 07:20:51.016638',
            1 => 'Agent - 167',
            2 => 'LOGOUT'
        ]
    ]
];


foreach ($pse_array as $value) {
    $total = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($value);
    ) /* $i+=2) */ {
        if ($value[$i][2] === "LOGIN" && $value[$i + 1][2] === "LOGIN") {
            $i+=1;
        } else {

            $srtTime = strtotime($value[$i][0]);
            $endTime = strtotime($value[$i + 1][0]);
            $interval = $endTime - $srtTime;
            $total += $interval;
            $i+=2;
        }
    }
    echo gmdate("H:i:s", $total) . " Minutes <br>";
}
```

Working Bin: https://eval.in/406539

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeout = strtotime('00:30') - strtotime('00:00');

foreach ($pse_array as $value) { // loop by user
    $total = 0;
    $login = false;                          // time of login  
    foreach ($value as $item)  {             // loop by entry
        if ($item[2] == 'LOGIN') {
           //if ($login) $total += $timeout; // two login successively
                                             // you can remove this
            $login = $item[0];               // save login time
            continue;
        }
        $srtTime = strtotime($login);        // if here, status = LOGOUT
        $login = false;                      // mark that previos was logout 
        $endTime = strtotime($item[0]);      // further your code
        $interval = $endTime - $srtTime;
        $total += $interval;                 // You receive interval in sec
    }
    echo $total/60 . " Minutes <br>";       
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. You're adding a 30 minute timeout? because some sessions are longer than 30 minutes so will that force a logout??

Comment: i add $timeout only when login -login situation. Yuo can remove this line, as i've written

Comment: if you remove it, new value of login willsave. so, you skip 1st login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84200/discussion-between-b0w3rb0w3r-and-splash58).